# Compare two files

Tags: text-processing

I have two files in UNIX.
1st file is Entity and Second File is References. 1st File has only one column named Entity ID and 2nd file has two columns Entity ID | Person ID.

I want to produce a output file where entity id's are matching in both the files.

Entity File

```
624197
624252
624264
624276
624280
624309
624317
```

Reference File

```
624252|624346
624264|1070122
624264|624346
624276|624588
624280|624346
624280|624582
624298|624588
624319|333008
624330|624588
```

Output File

```
624252|624346
624264|1070122
624264|624346
624276|624588
624280|624346
624280|624582
```

Entity Files has 90K Records and Reference file has 200K Records. Is there an efficient way to produce the third file ?
Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: The two files are sorted?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your files are both sorted:

```
join -j1 -t\| entity.txt reference.txt
```

If they're not sorted, sort them:

```
sort entity.txt -o entity-sorted.txt
sort reference.txt -o reference-sorted.txt
join -j1 -t\| entity-sorted.txt reference-sorted.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a bash / zsh one-liner. Assuming your data is contained in files named `entity` and `reference`, just type:

`for i in $(cat entity); do grep ^$i reference; done`

in a console.

Also, you can redirect the whole output to an  `output` file, as

`for i in $(cat entity); do grep ^$i reference; done > output`

Comment: He wants the first column to match, you'd need to change the `grep` to `^$i`

Comment: @Kevin: you're absolutely right! Edited in consequence.

Comment: `for i in $(cat entity)` is a bad idea due to the way that `$(` handles word splitting. Use `while IFS= read -r` instead.

Comment: @ChrisDown, Dalker: `sed -e 's/^/^/' -e 's/$/|/' | grep -F - reference >output`

Answer (score 0):

A solution using *Perl*:

Content of **entity.txt**:

```
$ cat entity.txt
624197
624252
624264
624276
624280
624309
624317
```

Content of **reference.txt**:

```
$ cat reference.txt 
624252|624346
624264|1070122
624264|624346
624276|624588
624280|624346
624280|624582
624298|624588
624319|333008
624330|624588
```

Content of Perl script:

```
$ cat script.pl
use warnings;
use strict;

## Check arguments.
@ARGV == 2 or die qq[Usage: perl $0 <entity-file> <reference-file>\n];

## File in process.
my $process_file = 1;

## Hash to save entities.
my %entity;


while ( <> ) {
        ## Process file of entities. Remove leading and trailing spaces, and save the
        ## number to a hash.
        if ( $process_file == 1 ) {
                s/\A\s*//;
                s/\s*\z//;
                if ( defined $_ ) { $entity{ $_ } = 1 }
                next;
        }

        ## Process file of references. Get first field and search it in the hash.
        ## If found, print the line.
        my @f = split /\|/, $_, 2;
        if ( exists $entity{ $f[0] } ) {
                print;
        }

} continue {
        ## Increment number when end processing first file.
        if ( eof ) { ++$process_file }
}
```

Running the script without arguments:

```
$ perl script.pl
Usage: perl script.pl <entity-file> <reference-file>
```

Running the script with arguments and result:

```
$ perl script.pl entity.txt reference.txt 
624252|624346
624264|1070122
624264|624346
624276|624588
624280|624346
624280|624582
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe I'm missing something? Please correct me if I'm wrong:

```
$ while read id;do grep $id reference ;done <identity 
624252|624346
624264|1070122
624264|624346
624276|624588
624280|624346
624280|624582
```

Looking at your source files, they were already sorted, but my solution should work regardless of whether they are sorted or not, I believe.

And to output to another file:

```
$ while read id;do grep $id reference ;done < identity > newoutput.out
```